# Devicemotion in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a pretty standard WebView set up with javascript enabled. On the HTML end, I am running shake.js by alexgibson (https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/).

I cannot get the shake event to trigger in the WebView. I have combed through the documentation and searched through forums but can't find any solution for this.

Have I missed something, or is devicemotion not supported by WebView?

The shake event works in mobile Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You could include some code maybe in jsfiddle so we can replicate your issue. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your reply! I have actually figured out what's causing the issue. Turns out if you fix the orientation in the manifest, devicemotion will stop working. Hope this helps anyone who faces the same issue.